# import classes from org.rda in java language

Tags: java, random, import, package

My question is very basic. I wanted to use the randomX in my java code.

[jgap.sourceforge.net/javadoc/3.01/org/jgap/util/randomLEcuyer.html](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/javadoc/3.01/org/jgap/util/randomLEcuyer.html)

sample code from here:

https://code.google.com/p/fractalproject/source/browse/FractalProject/src/org/dla/model/DlaModel.java?spec=svn40&r=40

I am already using another package, lets say MyProj, with other files of my current code.
I used the following lines,

```
package MyProj;
import org.jgap.util.randomLEcuyer
```

But eclipse does not recognize the randomLEcuyer. I appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have two package declarations in your code:

```
package MyProj;
package org.dla.model;
```

This is invalid. Second, the class you want to use, as the javadoc you linked to indicates, is `org.jgap.util.randomLEcuyer`, and not `org.rda.dice.randomx.randomLEcuyer`.

Finally, I would be careful in using a class that doesn't even respect the basic Java naming conventions: classes should start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: thank for answer. If I remove the package org.dla.model; and only import org.jgap.util.randomLEcuyer, java still do not recognize org.jgap.

Comment: And have you put the jar file of this library in your build path?

Comment: I downloaded the jgap package from http://jgap.sourceforge.net/doc/install.html and added it to build path. still, eclipse does not recognize the randomLEcuyer class.

Comment: What did you put to the build path, and how did you do it? You didn't put the whole zip file in the build path, did you? If so, extract it, and only put the jgap.jar in the build path. The zip contains everything: the source files, the documentation, the build files, etc.